# C# different syntax in formatting numbers

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I got a simple question regarding formatting numbers in C#.

I have a format like this

```
{0:0.00######################}
```

which was suggested by [this website](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/), which basically showing at least 2 decimal places of a number.

Then [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPt) has suggested a different format string

```
0.00######################
```

Now, I understand the former and latter have functional differences. For instance, I should use the former in string.Format() calls and the latter in Decimal.ToString() calls. But what I'd like to know is what's the importance in having the curly braces and the

```
0:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The colon is a _section separator_.  It allows you to specify different formats for positive, zero and negative values.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx) for all the details.

Comment: Why not use `MDSN` for as a reference point here is a good site with some different formats for numeric values http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `String.Format`, you can have more than one "item" which will be formatted.  This is determined by using `{n}` where `n` is the index into the list of values:

```
var result = string.Format("Arg1 == {0}, Arg2 == {1}", arg1, arg2);
```

This isn't required with `Decimal.ToString` and similar since there is only ever one value.

The `0:` is really just `{0}`, and `:` is used to break out the format specification (everything after the `:` is effectively the same as what the `ToString` methods use).

Answer (score 2):

When using `String.Format`, the curly braces indicate that you are placing a parameter to be replaced by a string.  The `0` indicates that it is the first parameter, so for example consider the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "A", "B", "C"));
```

Would output "A B C".  Whereas:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{2} {0} {1}", "A", "B", "C"));
```

Would output "C A B".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces is used as a "sign" to be replaced with the value. Number in the curly braces (0 based index) is the index pointing the value.

Example:

`string.Format("{0:#,##0} {1:#,##0} {0:#,##0}", 2345, 6789);`

Will resulting:

`2,345 6,789 2,345`